# How to pass the credentials along with username and password in powershell command

Tags: powershell, credentials

I'm trying to enter a remote session using powershell. I have created the following command, however it asks for a password to enter it manually and then it connects. I was looking with out a prompt for password

```
Enter-PSSession <IPaddress> -Credential Administrator
```

I have run the following:

```
$username = "Administrator"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "******" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList($username, $password)
$serverNameOrIp = "*****"

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $serverNameOrIp -Credential $cred
```

Following is the error:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server ****** failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There
are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or
use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\cred.ps1:6 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $serverNameOrIp -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (******:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Please note that remote server is in trusted host list

Comment: "Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names." - Based on this message, you cannot authenticate with a local user Windows account, or it''s as simple as your stored credential is wrong. Debug the script line by line using PowerShell ISE to determine if the last command contains exactly what you expected. Make sure the Windows Remote Management service is started. Make sure the is added the the host's WinRM TrustedHosts

Comment: Have a look at this post for potential solution https://superuser.com/questions/1806245/scheduled-robocopy-in-powershell-from-webdav-shares-not-work-with-iis-share-but/1806479#1806479 as it may be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a credential object this way :

```
$passwd = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String <your password>

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
-argumentlist "Domain\User",$passwd
```

You may then pass the `$cred` object as the value of the  `-Credential`
parameter like this: `-Credential $cred`.

You may find more options that you may adapt if needed in the post
[Windows PowerShell give password in command Enter-PSSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764288/windows-powershell-give-password-in-command-enter-pssession).

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I have the server which is not in a domain.
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server ***** failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There
are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

Comment: Could you please add these critical details to your post? Add also what your commands look like (as much as possible), then drop me a comment.

Comment: Have added in the original post

Comment: One small remark : The username might need to be "Domain\Administrator". If that doesn't help, here's a long shot: [link](https://itluke.online/2019/12/03/solved-0x80090311-occurred-while-using-kerberos-authentication/).